# Flink Gelly - Type mismatch while creating graph

Tags: scala, apache-flink, gelly

I am new to Apache Flink and Gelly and I use the Scala API. I hava a DataSet of vertices and a DataSet of edges and I am trying to create a graph like this:

```
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
// correct result
val edges: DataSet[Edge[Long, Long]] = (some transformations here)
//also correct result
val vertices: DataSet[Vertex[Long, String]] = (some transformations here)
//in the line below I get the errors
val graph = Graph.fromDataSet(vertices, edges, env)
```

And I get the following errors:

```
Type mismatch,expected: 
  DataSet[Vertex[NotInferedK,NotInferedVV]], actual: DataSet[Vertex[Long,String]]

Type mismatch,expected: 
  DataSet[Edges[NotInferedK,NotInferedEV]], actual: DataSet[Edge[Long,Long]]

Type mismatch,expected: 
  org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment, actual: org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you imported `Graph` from Gelly's Java API. Try to import the Scala version of `Graph` using `import org.apache.flink.graph.scala.Graph`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: It says that there is  not such package. If it helps at all I have imported maven dependencies of gelly like this:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-gelly</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
And my import of graph is import org.apache.flink.graph.{Graph, Vertex, Edge}

Comment: It appears that I had the wrong maven dependency for gelly. The correct one is
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-gelly-scala</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>